# How to create app from lightning resources?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I already manage to create an app running at https://mydomain.lightning.force.com/c/myFirstApp.app in developer console.

```
<aura:application access="global">
    <lightning:container src="{!$Resource.hello + '/index.html'}"/>
</aura:application>
```

There is also a apex class that used in that page.

How can I create app from those resources?

Answer (score 0):

In '`Quick Find`' search for '`Lightning App Builder'` -> create a `new App page` and drop your component in this app page and '`Activate`'

Comment: I can't find those components in leftside bar. there is only visualforce page that available.

Comment: Also adding `<apex:page >
    <apex:slds />
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <script>
 $Lightning.use("c:myFirstApp", function() {});
  </script>
</apex:page>` to try to load my app does not work